# How to write function that will compile without warnings, Exectued conditionally with close and open vars

Tags: pine-script, trading

In my code I'm collecting and calculating some values across all bars and at the end I have such condition:

```
if barstate.islast
    float tosMin = // get it from calculated data
    float tosMax = // get it from calculated data
    int periodToCheck = // get if from calculated data
    bool someOldState = // get it from calculated data
    bool newState = someOldState
        for period=periodToCheck to 1
            if open[period] < tosMin or close[period] < tosMin
                newState := false
            if open[period] > tosMax or close[period] > tosMax
                newState := true
        
        // real-time bar
        if barstate.isnew // when last bar opens
            if open < tosMin
                newState := false
            if open > tosMax
                newState := true
        
        if barstate.isconfirmed // when last bar closes
            if close < tosMin
                newState := false
            if close > tosMax
                newState := true

        // do something with newState
```

As You can see I have some logic inside `barstate.islast` condition scope. What I would like is to rewrite this logic inside scope to function that will receve on the input: tosMin, tosMax, periodToCheck and someOldState and calculate newState but when I try to write such function I have always warning like this:

```
The function nameOfTheFunction should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
```

The reason why I would like to rewrite it is because I have in many places such logic that is calculated during `barstate.islast` condition.

Any ideas how to make this logic reusable because it seems functions is not good way to do it?

So far I tried to do something like this:

```
// calculating data on every bar    

f_reusableFunction(_tosMin, _tosMax, _periodToCheck, _oldState) =>
    bool newState = _oldState
    for period=_periodToCheck to 1
        if open[period] < _tosMin or close[period] < _tosMin
            newState := false
        if open[period] > _tosMax or close[period] > _tosMax
            newState := true
            
    // real-time bar
    if barstate.isnew // when last bar opens
        if open < _tosMin
            newState := false
        if open > _tosMax
            newState := true
            
    if barstate.isconfirmed // when last bar closes
        if close < _tosMin
            newState := false
        if close > _tosMax
            newState := true
    newState

if barstate.islast
    float tosMin = // get it from calculated data
    float tosMax = // get it from calculated data
    int periodToCheck = // get if from calculated data
    bool someOldState = // get it from calculated data
        
    bool newState = f_reusableFunction(tosMin, tosMax, periodToCheck, someOldState) // here I have warning
    
    // do something with newState then reuse many times f_reusableFunction with different input parameters and periods calculated based on data collected in main script context.
```

Comment: Please post the entire script, including the function that throws this warning. You probably call your function in an `if` or a loop, while it must be called in the main script context.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to call this extracted function in if context when `barstate.islast` is true. I can't call it in main script context because I don't know input values in main context. I updated my question with solution that I tried.

Comment: Not sure you're approaching the problem the right way. Could you please explain in your question what you're actually trying to accomplish. Also, posting the entire script would help to determine if it can be rewritten to do what you intend. You might want to read about the Pine [execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html), which explains that your entire script runs at every bar. That's an essestial concept that's different from classical development languages.